# Stacked images parent div height

Tags: css, image, position, absolute, stacked

I have a dynamic image gallery with several images stacked on top of each other (using position: absolute; top:0; left:0 and opacity:0). And thumbnails are placed at the bottom (so the thumbnails need to be beneath the tallest image). Then the user clicks on a thumbnail, and the appropriate stacked image is shown.

I'm having difficulty putting the thumbnails beneath the stacked images, because positioning absolutely takes the images out of the flow, so the parent div has no height... If all the images have a fixed height, my solution is to use position absolute on all but the first image (so that the first image sets the height of the parent div, with the thumbnails underneath this div).
But if I have images with different heights, I want the thumbnails underneath the tallest image.

The gallery is also responsively sized (i.e. the gallery is on the left hand side, 50% of the width of the window).

Here is my html:

```
<div id="product-gallery">
    <div id="slides">
        <div class="slide active"><img...></div>
        <div class="slidee"><img...></div>
        <div class="slide"><img...></div>
        ...
    </div>

    <div id="thumbnails">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to rely on server side scripting or javascript to find the height of the tallest image... I like to keep everything minimalist :) But CSS3 is fine.

Many many thanks for any tips.

Comment: does passing a `padding-bottom: 20%` to `slides` and height `20%` to thumbnails do the trick? You could try to resize the images to 100% height.

Comment: You say no javascript, so how does the gallery function? Radio buttons?